# FormSetView save with Django Extra Views

Tags: django, django-forms

as shown in the following code i am trying to save the formset once it is validated. but i always get `object has no attribute 'save'`error. its great if someone can help me to use `FormSetView` to save and update data using forms.

```
from extra_views import FormSetView
from foo.forms import MyForm

class MyFormSetView(FormSetView):
    template_name = 'myformset.html'
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = 'success/'

    def formset_valid(self, formset):
        formset.save()
        return super(MyFormSetView, self).formset_valid(formset)
```

Comment: Does the `MyForm` inherit from `ModelForm`?

Comment: Yes, this here's my form.
`class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
        model = customer
        widgets = {
            'birthday': birthdaySelector(),
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ModelFormSetView` and then override your widget:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = customer

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['birthday'].widget = birthdaySelector()


class MyFormSetView(ModelFormSetView):
    template_name = 'myformset.html'
    model = customer
    success_url = 'success/'
    form_class = MyForm
```

No need to define `formset_valid`, `ModelFormSetView` saves formset automatically.

Comment: thank you @mariodev. your solution does exactly what i wanted to do.